The issue of try_files configure in nginx.conf
my nginx version is 1.16.1. this is my try_filse configure:
location / {
     root /home/nginx/html/dist/;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location = /index.html {
     root  /home/nginx/html/dist/;
}

as what said on nginx.org, if $uri and $uri failed. will redirect to /index.html. pay attention to my root configure and i do not configure index config, so the index default value will be index.html.

create index.html in file path /home/nginx/html/dist/home/nginx/html/dist/index.html
127.0.0.1/home/nginx/html/dist/ in browser. defalut index file, index.html will be found, so the finally file path found by nginx is that rootpaht + rui + default index file = /hmoe/nginx/html/dist/home/nginx/html/dist/idnex.html
if index.html existed in the file path of step1, it works. but there was no index.html, failed. Refer to nginx.org, the request will be indirect to from /home/nginx/html/dist/home/nginx/html/dist/index.html to the root path /home/nginx/html/dist/index.html.
but the result awlays 403 forbiden.

i trace the source code and debug them step by step, if redirection triggered .this branch must be tirggerd.
enter link description here but tf->names is /index.html, never be null.
so the reindrect function will be called.
enter link description here
but always goto to this code , 403 forbiden. because open file failed in the ngx_http_static_modue.
enter link description here
if tf->names is /index.html, this record never be null, the branch and redirect never be triggerd, maybe a bug.

bro, i know what you said, i'm not agree with you , it's a kind of internal redirect.  "If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri" this what nginx.org said. I analysis this issue from source code level , just like what i said , the function of  ngx_http_internal_redirect seems never be called in try_files module.

@Phil hi Phil, do not forget to recovery the vote for my question. idk why my question marked useless or unclear. if you did not vote -1 , ignore my complaints. :)

idk why my question was voted -1.  the man who challenged me deleted his comments, then run away, and maybe forget cancel his void -1 . fell very upset. :(

has sovled, misunderstanding of try_files. i have asked same question on nginx slack community. get correct answer. anywhy thank you anyone even that guy vote -1.
